# delete query for mysql using c

Tags: mysql, c

can anyone tell me the correct query  to delete values from mysql db table,in my case the table name and id are accepted from the user and the row is deleted based on id.This is my query

```
 sprintf(Query,"DELETE FROM ('%s') where id = (%d)",tb1,idt1) ;
 /*table name is in form of string and id is int */

 mysql_query(conn,Query);
```

Comment: what's wrong with your query ?

Comment: Be very careful to avoid SQL injection attacks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove parentheses around the table name:

```
sprintf(Query,"DELETE FROM '%s' where id = (%d)",tb1,idt1) ;
```

MySQL considers queries like this syntax errors:

```
delete from (mytable) where id=2;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(mytable) where id=2' at line 1

(I'll assume that you know everything about [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/), and that neither `tb1` nor `idt1` are constructed from user input in any shape or form).

Comment: thanks man,actually i writing this code and making it into a library file and accessing it as a header from my main source file,it wont be vulnerable to injection attacks or will it still be???

Comment: @user1841645 The organization of your code does not matter as much as does the code path through which the data goes leading to this call. The only string here is `tb1` - make sure that it is never read from a user input, for example, comes from a compile-time constant or a configuration file that you control. This will ensure that your statement is not vulnerable to the attack.